# parsing event data: Unexpected token o

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I am getting an error in browser console..
Runner: Error parsing event data: Unexpected token o 
pls dont see js console..

providing my code below...
it shows some kind of parsing data error..
http://jsbin.com/bahefuracehe/26/edit

```
 require.config({
          paths : {
            backbone : '//jashkenas.github.io/backbone/backbone-min.js',
            underscore : '//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js',
            jquery : '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
            marionette : 'http://marionettejs.com/downloads/backbone.marionette.min.js'
          },
          shim : {
            jquery : {
              exports : 'jQuery'
            },
            underscore : {
              exports : '_'
            },
            backbone : {
              deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
              exports : 'Backbone'
            },
            marionette : {
              deps : ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
              exports : 'Marionette'
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: From your title alone, I'm guessing you're attempting to parse the string `[object Object]` as JSON somewhere. `JSON.parse` reads the `[` as the start of an array, but then expects an opening `"`, a number, or a nested object or array.

Comment: There isn't enough context in the jsbin to really understand what is going on here, especially with the requriejs annotations (or what I am assuming are annotation). What is being returned from the endpoint for your sportsdata collection?

Comment: @apsillers: can you update my jsbin since its confusing...i am providing my json link http://jsbin.com/mulacesuhape/1.js